# PostGIS functions integrated in php example?

Tags: php, function, postgresql, geocoding, postgis

I'm writing a client for a postgreSQL database with PostGIS functions. this client of course communicates through php. However I'm looking for a proper documentations for available postGIS functions that i can call from my php files.

I would really appreciate if I could get a simple example of how postGIS function is integrated in php.

Cheers :)

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/pgconf/integrating-postgis-in-web-applications only thing I could find. It's a long read...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgis are stored procedures available at some schema in your postgresql database.
If you have PDO you can write procedures that call then quite close like objects.
See PHP PDO for fetch modes available.

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
class Postgis extends PDO
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->pg = new PDO( PDO_DB_DSN );
    $this->pg->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  }
  public function makePoint( $x, $y )
  {
    $preparedStatement = $this->pg->prepare( 'SELECT public.st_makepoint( ?, ? )' );
    $preparedStatement->execute( array( $x, $y ) );
    return $preparedStatement->fetchColumn();
  }
}

try
{
  $postgis = new Postgis();
  $point = $postgis->makePoint( 34, 44 ); //point holds the binary string of a point without srid
  var_dump( $point );
}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
  // any errors here
  var_dump( $e->getMessage() );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS lists all its types and functions on its website, for example here is the [Version 1.5 reference documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/reference.html). You can call these functions as SQL, just as you are calling any other SQL from the PHP.

So using PHP's built-in PostgreSQL function, you could do something like:

```
$result = pg_query_params('
    SELECT ST_Distance( location, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point($1, $2), 27700) )
    FROM table WHERE id=$3', array(400000, 300000, 123) );
```

To get the distance in metres from (400,000, 300,000) in the British grid-reference system to the location column of row 123 in your database table.

There might well be PHP wrappers around PostGIS functions, but I'm afraid I'm not aware of any